# Tkinter Check if StringVar is not empty

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a StringVar with Tkinter, I want to check that it is not empty. When I run the following condition, it is accepted while the variable is empty.

```
    if self.var:
        print(self.var)
```

The printed variable is PY_VAR1.

```
    if self.var!= 'PY_VAR1':
        print(self.var)
```

The printed variable is also PY_VAR1.

How to check that the value of self.var is not equal to PY_VAR1?

When I use get, it doesn't work either

```
    if self.var.get():
        print(self.var.get())
```

And when I change the value of self.var, with get (), nothing happens.

```
self.bouton = ttk.Button(self, text="print var", command=self.printvar)

def printvar(self):
      print(self.var.get())
```

When I click on the button, the value of self.var is displayed and even when I change the value of self.var (), the new value is displayed. But I want to display the new value of self.var without clicking on the button. I want it to display dynamically.

Comment: im not sure but try using `root.update()` ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to make any sense. The only place you call `select_folder` is from a button that isn't created until you call `select_folder`. Please try to create a complete [mcve] - it's really hard to understand what you're asking when we only have a few lines of code. We definitely don't want your whole program, but we need more than what you've posted. If you're truly just asking how to check if a stringvar is empty, what you're doing will work.

Comment: It was just a placement error.

Comment: Why don't you just call `select_folder()` after you have chosen a folder inside the callback called by menu action?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Printing the Var itself is pointless - you'll just get an automatically-generated name, such as "PYVAR1".  You need to call `.get()` on the Var to retrieve its actual value.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you use get, and you update, it doesn't work

Comment: Then you're either setting the wrong var, or calling `.get()` before the var has had a chance to be set, or any of numerous other things that we can only guess at because you haven't shown the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

**Try these:**

```
# no.1
if len(string_variable.get()) == 0:
    do_task()

# no.2
'''We use try-except function so we don't get a ValueError if the specified character 
isn't present in the if-condition'''
try:
    if string_variable.index("Any character in a word that needs to be checked"):
        '''If you want to check "PY_Var1", just type('1') or any other character in 
        the if-condition.'''
        do_task()
except:
    do_task()

# If none work, try storing the StringVar in another variable.
new_string_variable = string_variable.get()
if len(new_variable_string) == 0:
    do_task()

# To check if the string variable(StringVar) isn't equal to "any_string".
if (string_variable.get()) != "any_string":
    do_task()
```

*If you still have any problem, feel free to ask any questions!*